# Logging into ESPN using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to automate some tasks on ESPN and I first need to log into my account since I get redirected to the login page when I try to access an ESPN page. Here's the login form:

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="https://r.espn.go.com/espn/memberservices/pc/login">
<input type="hidden" name="failedAttempts" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="SUBMIT" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="failedLocation" value="http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fgames.espn.go.com%2Fffl%2Ffreeagency%3FteamId%3D1%26leagueId%3D39669&e=1">
<input type="hidden" name="aff_code" value="espn_fantgames">
<input type="hidden" name="appRedirect" value="http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/freeagency?teamId=1&leagueId=39669">
<input type="hidden" name="cookieDomain" value=".go.com">
<input type="hidden" name="multipleDomains" value="true">
<NOSCRIPT><input type=hidden name=noscript value=true></NOSCRIPT>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="bodyCopy"><tr>
<td width=15%><b>MEMBER NAME:</b></td>
<td width=1%>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="username" size="16" maxlength="64" value="" class="select"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>PASSWORD:</b></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" size="16" maxlength="25" value="" class="select"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="select"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Here's my python program:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fgames.espn.go.com%2Fffl%2Ffreeagency%3FteamId%3D1%26leagueId%3D39669")

username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username.send_keys("*******")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys("*******")
```

When I try to find the "username" element, I get a NoSuchElementException. I've tried looking it up online. Others have suggested switching frames, however, the login form doesn't seem to be in another frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting above login form, when you open the login page. I got something like this: `<label>
                                <span class="name ng-binding">Username or Email Address</span>
                                <input type="text" autocapitalize="none" ng-model="vm.username" ng-pattern="/^[^<&quot;>]*$/" placeholder="Username or Email Address" ng-required="" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-required" tabindex="0" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false">
                            </label>`

Comment: May be they have different login form for different location.

Comment: have u tried with answer that works for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is working fine to me--
**implement wait, it is mandatory in this case** let the page be loaded before any DOM query!

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin")
#implement wait it is mandatory in this case
WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)")))
frms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//iframe)")

driver.switch_to_frame(frms[2])
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input)[1]").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input)[2]").send_keys("pass")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button").click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
time.sleep(4)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. I noticed though that the list of iframes would sometimes get 3 or 4 iframes, but the login form would always be in the last iframe of the list so I just had to change:
driver.switch_to_frame(frms[2])
to
driver.switch_to_frame(frms[len(frms)-1])

Comment: FWIW my results are the opposite of mswis731's. I only have success if I use `driver.switch_to_frame(frms[2])`

Comment: @kuzzooroo may be the site structure is changed, better to inspect the web elements and modify the code accordingly.