# Is phantomjs a good solution for getting data from espn site?

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to build a web tool that gets data from my fantasy sport leagues for further analysis.
In order to do that, my tool needs to log in using espn login page:
http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin
as unfortunately ESPN got rid of their API.

I was trying to use various .NET webbrowser controls here (last one was GeckoFX) but couldn't get it working.

The problems:

- the page DOM is created dynamically with all the login controls added to an iframe element. Hence it's not possible to find them in the .NET code. I managed to find a solution for that with injecting javascript into the page. The script found all the controls (just using the list of input controls because none has ID attached to it) and setting the login data, then clicking the button.
- login then failed because the page is build with AngularJS and the model didn't notice my changes.

After many tries I abandoned this way and started looking for something else. One of suggestions I got was to try PhantomJS.
I know already that it can work with angular pages but still can't solve the problem of dynamic dom manipulation.

- when I try **document.getElementsByName** - I get nothing from the login controls as document just seems to hold the initial page structure
- I know that I can use **page.content** but looks like it's just a string with no possibility to get elements from.

Do I miss an existing solution to that problem?
Or maybe there's some other technology I could use here?

I know that others tried using python/selenium
[Logging into ESPN using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326459/logging-into-espn-using-selenium)
but I'm completely green in that area and have no idea if my hosting would be appropriate for such solutions so would prefer using .NET/js.

Thanks in advance for help!

*Edit*
Here's the example of code I tried:

```
page.open('http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin', function(status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {

      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
      //this one will return 0
      var numberOfInputControls = inputs.length;

      // and this will contain what I need but it's just a string
      var sourceWithChangedDOM = page.content;
      });
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Yes, PhantomJS is a good enough solution for your task because it is a real (albeit headless) browser. Please, edit your question to include a minimum working example of your PhantomJS script.

Comment: Thanks Vaviloff, indeed I hope I've found my solution in phantomJS. I added a sample of code I'm strugling with.