# Switch to the frame that contains the login prompts in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium to log into ESPN. A solution that used to work is detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33327501/2829764). In order to log in I need to find the frame that has the username and password fields and switch to that frame. Unfortunately, that numerical index of that frame isn't always the same. I decided to just try them all, but as soon as I've switched to one frame, switching to the next fails with `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <iframe class="ob-pifr"> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed`. So I'm looking for

- A way to switch frames without the `StaleElementReferenceException`
- A way to check whether a frame is the one I want before I switch to it
- Some other solution, though I'd prefer something introspective to a magic (and presumably fragile) formula like "It's always the third frame from the end)

Here's some sample code that leads to the `StaleElementReferenceException`:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin")
WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)")))

elem = None
frms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//iframe)")
print("Found {} frames", len(frms)) # Varies from 6 to 8
for count, frm in enumerate(frms):
    print("Trying frm[{}]".format(count))
    driver.switch_to.frame(frm)
    sleep(2)
    try:
        # The command below will fail the second time around with
        # `either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed`
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input)[1]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame id is `disneyid-iframe` which opens the login popup So first you need to switch into it

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("disneyid-iframe"))
```

and then perform sendkeys like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys("emailid")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys("password")
```

Other way to switch in frame is `ExplicitWait`. It wait until frame available once there then it get switched in

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "disneyid-iframe")))
```

Your Final code will be :

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get("http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "disneyid-iframe")))


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys("emailid") 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

**Note** : Please check syntax as per Python.